# How can i do git rebase after git pull request?

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-squash

I have a trouble git rebase.
because, I had pushed my local code to origin dev. And, I send a pull request to 'upstream'.
But, There are 1 PR and 7 commits like below the picture
[image]

I want to 7commits squash to 1 commit.

What shall I do?

( I have tried : 'git rebase -i HEAD~7', but I have met the message that 'error: cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.' )

Comment: Add your unstaged changes, and either stash or commit them.

Comment: Would you tell me the cli typing?. I had typed to terminal, there are shown the message to  'nothing to commit, working tree clean'

Comment: There will be nothing to commit if you do not first add your changes. Stage your changes with `git add --all`. If they are finished and you wish to commit them, follow that with `git commit`. If they are unfinished, use instead `git stash`. After rebasing, you can `git stash pop` to continue where you left off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you must commit, stash, or discard all your changes before rebasing. If your changes are complete, you most likely want to commit them (`git add --all` followed by `git commit`).

If they are not complete but you want to continue working on them later, use `git stash` to save your unfinished changes while also resetting to HEAD. Perform your rebase and then recover these changes with `git stash pop`.

To instead discard all your changes, `git reset --hard HEAD` will do the trick; `reset` to unstage your changes, `--hard` to discard them, and `HEAD` to specify the commit to which you are resetting. You should then be able to rebase.

It's worth noting that a stash or reset will not affect untracked files. To have these files included, you must first stage them with `git add`.